# Create renderable nested tree array like Menu Tree or Taxonomy Tree

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am getting a nested array with children property from the WebSerice. I want to create the render able array so that I can use "drupal_render" function to render final HTML. I looked at the 'menu_tree_output' and 'taxonomy tree" that Drupal generates, but there is not proper documentation that mention how to structure the array to make it render able nested list.

Lets make it short: How do I restructure the final array that I get from Webservice so that I can make it renderable using drupal_render api. Final output is nested list(Folder tree).

Answer (score 1):

`menu_tree_output` is not intended for rendering anything else than menus.

You should use something like [theme_item_list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) to render trees with your own data.

Here is an article explaining the usage of [How to create custom item list in Drupal 7](http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-create-custom-item-list-drupal-7) that theme function.

I would define my own custom `theme_item_list__something`, based on the native one, for full controll over markup.